# How to build jars with and without test classes with Spring Boot with Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using this to build a fat jar

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

I added this, which generated a *-test.jar, but it does not include any dependency, specifically TestNG classes necessary for running the test on command line.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

java -classpath target/mypackage-tests.jar MyTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG
    ...

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am trying to do the same but haven't found anything in spring-boot maven.. If you are willing to add plugin you could go down this route - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868786/how-to-build-jars-with-and-without-test-classes-with-spring-boot-with-maven